DOMPDF not working, returns 500 when trying to use "DejaVu Sans"
I cannot get my pdf generator to work. I'm using dompdf/dompdf library and I have a lot of trouble generating PDF I want. My issue is: every time I try to generate PDF with file that is using style with family-font: DejaVu Sans I get 500 ERROR and nothings happening.
When I delete line including "DejaVu Sans" everything works, but I need PDF file to handle extended Latin characters like "ążćłóńę". Is there any way to make this work, or any other way to use extended Latin in DomPdf?
PHP Generate:
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

$options = new Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);

$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

$php = file_get_contents("inputPdfData.php");

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->loadHtml($php);

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();


"inputPdfData.php"
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <title>PDF GENERATOR</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html">
<style>
    * {
        font-family: "DejaVu Sans", sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    ążćęłóńź
    ĄŻĘĆŹŁÓŃ
</body>
</html>

"composer.json"
{
    "require": {
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^2.0"
    }
}

Error I get:

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/FontMetrics.php:233


"500 Internal Server Error" is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging, diagnosing or resolving problems. You need to check the error logs on the server (or enable on-screen error reporting, if it's a development environment) to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the exact problem, and then moving on to trying to fix it. Without that detailed error message we cannot help you much.

Note that file_get_contents("inputPdfData.php"); will actually get the PHP script, not the HTML that is shown when that script is executed. Currently there's only HTML in that PHP script, so it doesn't matter, but when you add PHP code it won't get executed.

I've been able to find error log:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/FontMetrics.php:233

Normally after you have installed DOMPDF, the DejaVu TrueType fonts have been pre-installed to give dompdf decent Unicode character coverage by default.
Aother way (instead of using DejaVu) to use extended Latin in DomPdf (or to render polish fonts, etc), you may choose using Poltawski Nowy font.
The trick is to use google font, such as
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poltawski+Nowy:ital,wght@0,400..700;1,400..700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

So please find below a fully working code (modified based on your original code):
PHP (e.g. font1.php)
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

$options = new Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);

$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

$php = file_get_contents("inputPdfData.php");

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->loadHtml($php);

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();

inputPdfData.php
<html lang="pl">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poltawski+Nowy:ital,wght@0,400..700;1,400..700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<head>
    <title>PDF GENERATOR</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html">
<style>
    * {
        font-family: "Poltawski Nowy", sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

ążćęłóńź <br>
ĄŻĘĆŹŁÓŃ <br>

Stack Overflow is good 

</body>
</html>

See below for the result


I end up not using dompdf because of multiple issues.
For anyone struggling: try using other library mPDF worked like magic for me.
It worked first time with no issues about font or charset.
Maybe this will help someone avoid hours of searching for an answer (about dompdf)
